# google sheets triggers for email notification

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up an instantaneous email notification when a certain value (in this case hydrogen sulphide) exceeds a threshold on google sheets.

An example of the data:

```
          h2s      VFA
                F1     F2 
01/10/17  555   893    786
02/10/17  456   980    654
03/10/17  205   1021   875
04/10/17
05/10/17
06/10/17  345   987
```

I've got the following working code:

```
function readCell() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var h2s_value = sheet.getRange("B2").getValues();
    if(h2s_value>500) MailApp.sendEmail('emailaddress@gmail.com', 'High 
Hydrogen Sulphide Levels', 'Hydrogen Sulphide levels are greater than 500ppm ' + h2s_value );
};
```

It works when I run the code and an email is sent if the value of B2 exceeds 500. I would like to automate the code to run everytime the value is updated, and so an email is sent instantaneously if the threshold is reached. I tried using onChange triggers, but it's not working.

The problem is that if I put triggers on the main spreadsheet (which records a long list of lots of different parameters), I will get an email notification for every single change made on the spreadsheet- whether it's relevant to the value of interest or not. So I have created another sheet which summarises single key parameters just for that day. The daily key parameters are linked to the main spreadsheet, however when I make a change on the main spreadsheet, the script doesn't recognise the change as the value changes indirectly through the link in the formula.

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a trigger to respond to indirect changes on a spreadsheet? i.e. where the formula remains the same but the value changes.

If it's possible to have instantaneous triggers, this would be much preferred than time driven triggers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Lisa

--------------------------LATEST VERSION ---------------------------------------
Now I'm trying to work the code with multiple columns including for h2s and VFA (code below only contains code for VFA) , but I haven't been able to define more than one e.value and it only seems to run for the last column. Is it possible to define more than one e.value?

```
function onEdit (e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var range = e.range.columnStart;
  var watching_f1 = ss.getRange("Y6:Y");
  var watching_f2 = ss.getRange ("Z6:Z");

  // Only check the f1 values and send emails if cells in col "Y" changes
  if ((watching_f1.getColumn() <= range == range <= watching_f1.getLastColumn())) {
var vfa_f1 = e.values[0];
    if(vfa_f1>2500) {
      MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'High VFAs in Fermenter 1', 'Hi, High VFAs in Fermenter 1. VFA recorded at ' + vfa_f1);
}};

  // Only check the f2 values and send emails if cells in col "Z" changes
  if ((watching_f2.getColumn() <= range == range <= watching_f2.getLastColumn())) {
    var vfa_f2 = e.values[1]; 
    if(vfa_f2>2500) {
     MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'High VFAs in Fermenter 2', 'Hi, High VFAs in Fermenter 2. VFA recorded at ' + vfa_f2);
    }};
  }
```

Comment: The only way is to poll it with a time based trigger.

Comment: @LisaM `e.value` is only available if the [edited range is a single cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).  instead of `e.value` you will have to make a call to the sheet with `getRange().getValue()` for each `if()` statement

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the issue, narrowing down the range on which the [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) trigger runs the `MailApp.sendEmail()` would prevent other cell edits on the sheet from sending the extra emails.

```
function onEdit (e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var range = e.range.columnStart;
  var watching = ss.getRange("B1:B");

  // Only check the values and send emails if cells in col "B" changes
  if ((watching.getColumn() <= range == range <= watching.getLastColumn())) {
    var h2s_value = e.value; // Use the event object value to save a call to the sheet
    if (h2s_value > 500) {
     MailApp.sendEmail('emailaddress@gmail.com', 'High Hydrogen Sulphide Levels', 'Hydrogen Sulphide levels are greater than 500ppm ' + h2s_value );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hello @random-parts , thanks for your help! That's great, although the value which would actually be changing is on another sheet, cell B2 just records the latest value from the other spreadsheet. And the row changes every day, so I couldn't put it to a single cell value. But I suppose if I set the range for the column itself, that should work! I'll give that a try. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, would setting the range for a whole column, then send an email for every cell value that exceeds the limit? I am looking to find a way just to check the latest value only

Comment: I was planning to get the above to work with a column, and then send an email if it exceeds the limit only if the date matches todays date. But I've tried using the above for a column i.e getRange("A1:A10") and getRange(1,1,10,1), but neither works. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Watching a column changes the if statement a bit as it has to check if the edited cell is between 2 values - instead of just watching a single cell. Example is updated to reflect the entire column

Comment: @LisaM is the `latest value` always the last row in the column? If so, then only the last row of data in the column would need to be checked

Comment: the latest value is always the last row, however there are days where there is no data entered, so last row wouldn't work in this case. Each row of data begins with the date, so I was thinking of checking the column of data and matching todays date with the date in the first column. I've used matching and indexing to pull the data from the main spreadsheet to the key parameters spreadsheet, but not really sure how to use this in script/ if it's possible? @random-parts

Comment: I've added a simplified example of the main spreadsheet data in the question @random-parts

Comment: @LisaM Instead of having a second spreadsheet with `single key parameters` could you add those values to a new sheet within the main spreadsheet? That way `onEdit()` would still work. `onChange()` is not a useful trigger for your needs. When the main sheet has edits that are referenced/indirectly changes the daily sheet - onEdit will pick up the change in the daily sheet.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this @random-parts . the daily 'key parameters (kp)' sheet is a new sheet within the main spreadsheet. I did try using onEdit() on the kp sheet but it didn't record any indirect changes made through the main spreadsheet and the trigger would only run when a cell was directly edited on the kp sheet.

Comment: hi @random-parts . It works if I fill the blank spaces with a '-'. So that should do the trick! Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: I've got the script working for one column, but I'm looking to do multiple columns and at the moment the trigger only works for the latest column. I take it that the scripts run at the same time, so it takes the last e.value value? Is there a way to define multiple e.values? @random-parts

Comment: I've put the latest version in the original question